# Can we have a HMM where state transition is dependent on amount of time spent in states?

Tags: hidden-markov-models

Suppose I build a hidden markov model(HMM) with 2 hidden states - S1, S2. In normal HMM, we assume the state transitions P(S1|S2) and P(S2|S1) is same irrespective of the time spent in S1 and S2.  Is there a way to relax this assumption? e.g. In my use case - a better assumption may be -  Probaility of transtioning to S2 from S1 i.e. P(S2|S1) at time t, is a decreasing function of how much time is spent in S1 till time t. In other words, if more time is spent in a state, the probability of transitioning out of that state decreases. Is there a similar model in literature that I can use?